# Resetting Major Versions on All Lists and Libraries

Tags: custom-timer-job

I've been tasked to help enforce our governance to set the Major version limit on all lists that have versioning enabled.  I'm thinking of using a TimerJob to accomplish this.  However, I've been added a new requirement to be able to "white list" certain lists.  What is the best way to approach this?  A Custom list in Central Admin maybe?  Looking for suggestions.

Bismarck

Answer (score 1):

I have had to similar in the past. I would create a Timer Job to crawl your sites and look for lists with versioning on and then check for majors. like you say then use a list to store which ones not to touch.

For new lists, why don't you staple a feature (with receiver code) that sets Majors on by default?

the other thing you need to be careful of is those lists that have versioning on with draft docs in place. You need a plan of what to do with them...